# for loop unintentionally breaking at if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop, primes

I am trying to determine the largest prime factor of a number by working backwards from the largest possible factor. Once a factor is found, I test to see if it is prime by using the PrimeTest3 function within the original function.

However, it is not giving me the answer I am expecting for the number 13195. When I test the code as shown above using the 'this passed the test' statement, I can see that it is skipping from the first factor found (2639) to the last factor found (5), and strangely, when logging the the result of passing i through PrimeTest3, it shows up as false, even though it had to have been true to pass the if statement in the first place.

```
var largestPrimeFactor3 = function (num) {
    function PrimeTest3(a){
        if (a<=1 || a%1!=0) 
            return false;

        limit = Math.ceil(Math.pow(a,.5));

        if (a%2==0 || a%3==0) 
            return false;
        if (a==2 || a==3) 
            return true;

        for (i=6;i<limit;i+=6){
            if (a%(i-1)==0) 
                return false;
            if (a%(i+1)==0) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    for(var i = Math.floor(num/2); i>0; i--){
        console.log(i);
        if(num % i === 0 && PrimeTest3(i)){
            console.log('this passed the test:' + PrimeTest3(i));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
console.log(largestPrimeFactor3(13195));
```

Would really appreciate any help or clarification. Thanks!!

Comment: Better give us a start by adding a tag for the language.

Comment: thanks Jongware for the suggestion and thanks Lee for the edit!

Comment: Just a note: you are *not*  working backwards from the largest possible factor. For example, 3 * 17 = 51, sqrt(51) ≈  8, 17 > 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're having unexpected results because you're changing the value of `i` in `PrimeTest3`.

```
if(num % i === 0 && PrimeTest3(i)){ // i changed in PrimeTest3
    // now i is not what it was when originally passed in PrimeTest3
    console.log('this passed the test:' + PrimeTest3(i));
```

A fix would be to change:

```
for (i=6;i<limit;i+=6){
```

To:

```
for (var i=6;i<limit;i+=6){
```

This will localize the `i` variable to not change the other `i` variable outside `PrimeTest3`'s function scope.

While you're at it, localize `limit` to the scope of `PrimeTest3` by doing `var limit = ...` instead of just `limit = ...`.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop inside `PrimeTest3` is using the same variable `i` as the loop in `largestPrimeFactor3`. You need to declare this variable as local to the internal function, with a `var` declaration.

```
var largestPrimeFactor3 = function (num) {
    function PrimeTest3(a){
        if (a<=1 || a%1!=0) 
            return false;

        limit = Math.ceil(Math.pow(a,.5));

        if (a%2==0 || a%3==0) 
            return false;
        if (a==2 || a==3) 
            return true;

        for (var i=6;i<limit;i+=6){
            if (a%(i-1)==0) 
                return false;
            if (a%(i+1)==0) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    for(var i = Math.floor(num/2); i>0; i--){
        console.log(i);
        if(num % i === 0 && PrimeTest3(i)){
            console.log('this passed the test:' + PrimeTest3(i));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
console.log(largestPrimeFactor3(13195));
```